# Bounded extension

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

What are the easiest examples of a pairs of Banach spaces $X,Y$ such that

- $X\subseteq Y$ ($X$ is a closed linear subspace of $Y$)
- there is a bounded linear map $T\colon X\to Y$;
- there is no bounded extension $\hat{T}\colon Y\to Y$ of $T$?

Needless to say, I am interested in the structure of the operator $T$ rather than in its existence.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $X = C^1(0,1)$ and $Y = C^0(0,1)$ and the map $T = \frac{d}{dx}: C^1(0,1) \to C^0(0,1)$. Every densely defined unbounded operator will provide an example.

Comment: A little ambiguity: What if we asked $X$ be equipped with the norm induced by $Y$? $X$ would have to be non-complemented in $Y$, but it's the most I get...

Comment: Yes, $C^0(0,1)$ is not a Banach space under sup norm... Of course, I meant $X\subseteq Y$ and the norm is induced.

Comment: @Rumburak: Of course, it is your job to ask the question unambiguously... but I'll add an example later on.